# Large logo in centre of nav

Tags: html, css

She gave me a design, with a big logo in the middle (height is 100px, 6.250em) while the normal list items are 50px in height (3.125em). Now I don't know how to do this.

[This is what I have](http://jsfiddle.net/d92Ux/)

And this'll be the endresult:

[image: END]

So, can anyone help me?

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">fotoreportage</a></li>
            <li id="logo"><a href="#">navatushots</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">voorwaarden</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#c3c3c3;
}

nav{
    width:100%;

    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;

    background-color:#fff;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
}

nav li a{
    height:3.125em;
    line-height:50px;   

    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000; 
}

nav li#logo{
    height:100px;
    line-height:6.250em;    
    background-color:#595450;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: It says to me: **Access to this web site was blocked by an IT URL Filtering policy because of its category.** and then, `Category: Disease Vector`.

Comment: I'm going to check into that, in the meanwhile, here's a screenshot :)

http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/9281/schermafbeelding2013031v.png

Comment: I'd suggest you put replicate it on jsfiddle.net and share that link instead.

Comment: Ok, does this work for you?
http://jsfiddle.net/d92Ux/

Beside the regular CSS there is also the reset.css :)

Comment: I'm not sure what specific problem you want to address, but I would advise against putting the logo into the `nav` list, and suggest putting it into a `header` instead.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Well, in the CSS you can see that one of the listitems (the one in the middle) has to be larger than the rest: 100 px. (the rest is 50px).
Example: (this is the design)
http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/5386/schermafbeelding2013031z.png

Comment: And why can't you use 2 <li> groups, one for the left and one for the right of the logo? Is there a reason you're using ID's instead of classes (eg, are they being referenced from any javascript)

Comment: I know you have already accepted an answer but as you are using images of fixed heights, you could also do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/d92Ux/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide you a little re-thinking on your markup, here's a more kind of semantic solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh3X5/

```
<h1 title="NavatuShots">NavatuShots</h1>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li class="mid-left"><a href="#">fotoreportage</a></li>
        <li class="mid-right"><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">voorwarden</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The Logo is now wrapped in a H1, which contains the word "NavatuShots", but is not displayed due to "text-indent: -9999px;", instead your logo is shown with a background-image. It's also recommended, that you add your home-link to the H1, since people might try to click it.

The positioning of the logo is made by "position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0;". Then a negative margin of the half of the logo's width is added to the H1 element, so it's centered correctly.

On the other side, the ul-element isn't split up, I've added to helper classes, which provide some margin to the li-elements in the middle.

That's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, when I implement it, the letters 'portfolio' fall behind the h1.. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

As @DaveRook suggested in the comments, using separate `ul-li` sections would be much easier.

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/d92Ux/2/)

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">about</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">fotoreportage</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="logo"><a href="#">navatushots</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">portfolio</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">voorwaarden</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu">contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    background-color:#c3c3c3;
}
nav {
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#fff;
}
nav ul, nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav li a {
    height:3.125em;
    line-height:50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
nav li#logo {
    height:100px;
    line-height:6.250em;
    background-color:#595450;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to display the logo in its position but not stretch the `height` of its container, maybe this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/d92Ux/1/

**--EDIT--**

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d92Ux/4/

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Only one of the listitems is falling behind the 'logo'. How can I fix that?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you accepted an answer that doesn't do what you mention. Dream Eater's answer stretches even more the height of the container. BTW, I edited my answer and made a new jsfiddle.